# Linkin List on C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have created a list and put some values into it. My list has its contents copied into an array, and then printed. My question that I have is, how do I delete the list that I have created?

Here is my code:

```
void main()
{   
    std::list<char> list;

    while (1)
    {
        char in=0;
        while(1)
        {
            scanf("%c",&in);
            if(in=='\n') break;
            list.push_back(in);
        }
        char* array=new char[list.size()]; // create a dynamic array   
        list<char> first;
       std::copy(list.begin(),list.end(),array); // copy the data 
        for (int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++) printf("%c",array[i]);
                printf("\nsize of array is: %d\n", list.size());
                delete [] array; // destroy the dynamic array
    }
}
```

Comment: `list.clear()`? (if you want the empty the list). Otherwise, you don't have to delete your list, you didn't create it on the heap, nor does it hold pointers to data allocated on the heap.

Comment: Are you looking to just delete the list, or delete everything in the list also?

Comment: Difficult to see what your question is, You are deallocating the `array` you created when you called `delete`, for clearing the `std::list` of all its elements you just need a [list.clear()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/clear/).

Comment: This smells like homework to me...

Comment: Yes this is the function that i looked for. Thanks. Say it is deleting that is on the list, what functio do i use if i want to destroy the list?

Comment: You don't have to destroy the list.

Comment: Yes here, but i'm working on a bigger project and it's just a small function in it.

Comment: @Alexander: Once you call `std::list::clear()` it calls the destructors of all the elements in the list and `list.size()` becomes `0`, aka list has nothing left.If you had pointers as elements then you would have to explicitly call `delete` on each of the element but in this case nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to divine your meaning, I would guess that you want the list called 'list' to clear its contents after every iteration of the outer loop. list.clear() will do that, as will moving the declaration of list to within the outer loop. The destructor will properly free any resources you allocate and you will have a fresh instance on every iteration.